# Why the base class doesn't work in this multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, method-resolution-order

I am confused by the MRO and C3 linearization algorithm for explaining the following code, could you help me out, please?

```
class A(object):
    def go(self):
        print("A")

class B(A):
    def go(self):
        super(B, self).go()
        print("B")

class C(A):
    def go(self):
        # super(C, self).go()
        print("C")

class D(B, C):
    def go(self):
        super(D, self).go()
        print("D")

d = D()
d.go()
pprint.pprint(D.__mro__)

The Result is:
C
B
D
(<class '__main__.D'>,
 <class '__main__.B'>,
 <class '__main__.C'>,
 <class '__main__.A'>,
 <class 'object'>)
```

Another example is: if I uncomment the super statement in class C and comment the super statement in class B, the result will be "B  D", there is no C and A. Why ?!!!!!
(I do understand the depth-first, left to right rule, but……)

Comment: Why have you commented out C's super call? What's the purpose of the up variable/print?

Comment: Also please explain what you don't understand. The output is what I'd expect, given the code you have posted, so you'll need to be clearer what you expect to be different and why.

Comment: I just would like to understand the multiple inheritance well. So I tried different conditions to see the results.

Answer (score 1):

The `super()` method just finds the next method to be invoked based on MRO.

`D.go()` invokes `B.go()`, which would then invoke `C.go()`, which prints `C` and returns back to `B.go()` which prints `B` and finally returns back to `D.go()` which prints `D`

If you expect all the `go()` methods to be invoked, you have to uncomment the `super()` call in `C.go()`.

You can find a lot more information on MRO and `super()` call from Guido's own [blog](https://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html)

Comment: Thanks. I do read the blog you mentioned, but still a little confused by some scenarios

Answer (score 0):

From [Guido's blog](https://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html):

> The computation of the MRO was officially documented as using a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the classes as before. If any class was duplicated in this search, all but the last occurrence would be deleted from the MRO list.

So if you have, for instance:

```
class A: pass
class B(A): pass
class C(A): pass
class D(B, C): pass
```

Instead of a simple depth-first resolution order of `D, B, A, C, A`, the MRO removes all but the last instance of a repeated element, so you have `D, B, C, A`. In your case, your class `C` does not call it's `super()` (since you commented it out). Thus, unless I am mistaken, the MRO defers the call to `A` until after `C`, but since `C` doesn't call its `super()`, you never see `A.go()` called:

```
D.go() --> B.go() (--> A.go() removed by MRO) --> C.go() (x> A.go() not called)
```

Comment: Thanks your reply, now I understand. But, if the `B` doesn't call its `super()` and `C` calls its `super()`, why the result is "B\n D\n"? why the `C.go()` never prints?

Comment: I believe that once you reach anything that isn't calling it's `super()`, the resolution is over and you can stop searching for other methods. I could be wrong though...

Comment: I guess so, too. But couldn't find official explanation for it. Thanks so much!